# PriorityQueue not printing the things i want

Tags: java

Hi this is a test class I have put together before I proceed to my assignment, and I realize it is not working the way I want. Here is my class:

JobLog:

```
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class JobLog {
    private PriorityQueue<Job> log;

    public JobLog() {
        log = new PriorityQueue<Job>();
    }

    public void addJob(Job newJob) {
        log.add(newJob);
    }

    public void addJob(int clock, int exectionTime, int jobNumber,
            int priorityLevel) {
        Job newJob = new Job(clock, exectionTime, jobNumber, priorityLevel);
        addJob(newJob);
    }

    public Job getNextJob() {
        return log.peek();
    }

    public Job removeNextJob() {
        return log.remove();
    }
}
```

TestClass

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    JobLog waitline=new JobLog();
    Job Joba=new Job(3,3,4,12);
    Job Jobb=new Job(3,3,4,2);
    Job Jobc=new Job(3,3,4,3);
    Job Jobd=new Job(3,3,4,4);
    Job Jobe=new Job(3,3,4,5);
    Job Jobf=new Job(3,3,4,5);
    Job Jobg=new Job(3,3,4,1);

    waitline.addJob(Joba);
    waitline.addJob(Jobb);

    System.out.println(waitline.getNextJob());
}
```

I'm getting this result.

```
assignment3_csc225.Job@1db04ed
```

I want to return all the information of the job . How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to write a toString method for the job class so that java knows how to display it. What it appears you are getting is the default (Object) toString output.

Comment: cant i write (waitline.getNextJob()).getPriorityLevel (for example) to get priority level of the job?

Comment: if there is a method getPriortyLevel() in Job you could write `System.out.println(waitline.getNextJob().getPriorityLevel())` and it would print out the number associated with that priority level.

Comment: But it would be easy to write a toString() method in Job. Write something like `public String toString() {return "Priority: " + priorityLevel;}`

Answer (score 1):

You can overload the [toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method on the Job class to return the string describing a Job.

Now when you print out a Job, this string will be returned.

Comment: cant i write (waitline.getNextJob()).getPriorityLevel (for example)
to get priority level of the job?

Comment: @YuvinNg You can write whatever you like that makes sense to you and the compiler.